# reducing the effect of a parasitic capacitor!

Tags: noise, signal-processing, signal-to-noise

[image]

According to my text book, the second figure says that **the noise current returns to their source without flowing through z1**, how is that possible? if the noise returns why doesn't signal/ original current also return without flowing through z1?

Comment: In this circuit, Vn is entirely noise. There is no signal current. This shield is not used to strip noise out of a signal while letting the signal continue to R1.

Comment: ok!but how is it best(normally) to describe the process of removing the noise due to parasitic capacitance using a shield? and not affect our useful signal?

Answer (score 1):

Capacitive shields only work when noise is being coupled into you signal externally via electrostatic means. You have some rapidly changing high(ish) voltage (HF/AC) somewhere that has a little bit of capacitive coupling with your signal of interest, the shield... well acts as a shield, it provides a much lower impedance return path for the noise and because the shield is grounded (or connected to some low impedance source) it has very little AC voltage across it, because it has so little AC voltage across it, it doesn't produce strong electrostatic fields and so doesn't couple strongly with your signal.